# NSLog the address a pointer is pointing to

Tags: objective-c

I wanted to NSLog the address a pointer is pointing to. I came across [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/82291-nslogging-memory-address.html)
however I am still getting an error. This is my code

```
    Teacher* t = [[Teacher alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"t points to the address <%p>" &*t);//Error
```

The error is

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSString *' and 'Teacher')
```

Any suggestions on how I can print the address of the pointer ?

Comment: Did you try  NSLog(@"%@<%x>", object, object); That's what the link you are referring to suggests further on.

Comment: Don't do "&*t", use just t. The compiler probably things that you want to do a bitwise & between the string @"t point... " and *t.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax error is caused by a missing comma:

```
NSLog(@"t points to the address <%p>", &*t);
                             --------^
```

The compiler reads your expression as

```
(@"t points to the address <%p>") & (*t) // 'NSString *' & 'Teacher'
```

Apart from that, you can simplify `&*t` to `t`:

```
NSLog(@"t points to the address <%p>", t);
```